# Sequential request invocation in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

A web site, that requires authentication, provides a search service.
The search consists in two steps.

First, a request that retrieves basic information (stock, dimensions, etc) from a product serial number.

Second, given the previous search and a couple of additional fields the second request will show the product price.
The problem is that steps must be invoked in strict order.
For example, given two products `A` and `B`, the following sequence will produce an error -> `basic_info(A)`, `basic_info(B)`, `get_price(A)` => An error is shown because the server expects for `get_price(B)`.
Given that be authenticated is a must I can't discard cookies.
Is there a way to guarantee a sequential request invocation order in the bellow scenario?

```py
def after_auth_success(self, response):
    for product in prod_list:
        yield FormRequest("basic_info_url", ..., calback = self.on_basic_info)

def on_basic_info(self, response):
    yield FormRequest("get_price_url", ..., calback = self.on_price_info)

def on_price_info(self, response):
    #Scrape result... 
    #<price would be scraped correctly only if the requests are done in order> 
    yield result
```

Expected result:

```
Only one thread running the sequence 
basic_info_url | get_price_url |  basic_info_url | get_price_url ...
```

Actual result:

```
If CONCURRENT_REQUEST=1 => Invoke all basic_info_url and after invoke all get_price_url.
```

Comment: It's highly likely that you are tied to a single session once you authenticate. `after_auth_success` method generates multiple requests but with same session cookies and if server response is tied to them you'll get very confusing results. To prevent that you need to either queue products one by one or start multiple sessions - but it's hard to tell without having a link to the website you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to get the desired behaviour.
The idea is to make a kind of recursion, last step will return the whole result.
To iterate over the recursion we share the list using the meta attr.

```py
result = list()

def after_auth_success(self, response):
    first_prod = prod_list.pop(0)
    basic_url = build_url("basic_info_url", first_prod)
    yield FormRequest(basic_url, meta = {'prod_list': prod_list}, calback = self.on_basic_info)

def on_basic_info(self, response):
    yield FormRequest("get_price_url", meta = {'prod_list':response.meta['prod_list']}, calback = self.on_price_info)

def on_price_info(self, response):
    #Scrape result and add the result into a dict called node 
    result.append(result_node)
    prod_list = response.meta['prod_list']
    if prod_list:
        first_prod = prod_list.pop(0)
        basic_url = build_url("basic_info_url", first_prod)
        yield FormRequest(basic_url, meta = {'prod_list': prod_list}, calback = self.on_basic_info)
    else:
        yield {'data': result}
```